# Performance of -webkit-filter on a single div VS multiple divs

Tags: html, css, performance, browser, webkit

Suppose I have a css class:

```
.hue {
  -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(10deg);
}

/* arbitrary */
#box {
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
}
```

Which would have better performance in a browser?

```
<div class='hue'>
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

... or ...

```
<div id="box" class='hue'></div>
<div id="box" class='hue'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the performance in the browser would be the same because you're effectively adding the same attributes to the `<div>` either way. I think the issue here would more be relating to scalability, so you would have to think about what your goal is with your code and if you are going to need to edit it in the future.

The upside of the first option is that if you wanted to change the class you would only have to edit the outer `<div>` tag and your changes would be applied to all of the inner ones, but this gives you less control over each of those inner elements.

The second option gives your more control over each `<div>` and you can change one without having it impact any of the other content. However, if you wanted to add a bunch more of those same elements it would start to get messy having to make sure each one had the "box" ID and the "hue" class.

If I were you I would just weigh the pros and cons based on where you are trying to go with your site, and especially consider if you are going to need to scale it up in the future.

Comment: Lets say readability and editablity wasn't an issue, just scalability.  Which would run faster as you added more boxes?  Also, -webkit-filter is a type of CSS shader, which technically isn't an attribute inherited by child elements (you can stack filters by nesting).